# Difference between an array (numpy) and an index (pandas) object?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I'm confused as to the difference between an index object such as what you would get from `df.index` and an array object such as `df.index.values`(where `df` is a pandas dataframe)

In which cases should I use one over the other?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.index` is [immutable](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) so you cannot change it. for example, if you create an index object and then try to modify an element:

```
test_index = pd.Index([1, 2, 3])
test_index[0] = 2
```

This will throw a `TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations`

Whether you should use the index object or the array will depend on your use case so your question is a bit open ended. If you want to extract the index values and then modify them for some reason, then you'll want to use `df.index.values`, but if you are checking values within the index, then either would work.